# Laravel and Vue: Mapping values send from Vue to Laravel backend

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js

Fields in the frontend I'm working on are defined using camel-case notation. Ie:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" v-model.trim="form.firstName">
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" v-model.trim="form.lastName">
```

so, when submitting a form something like this gets passed:

```
{
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

and that's what the request in Laravel is gonna end up getting.

In Laravel, column names are "first_name", "last_name". At what point should I be mapping the values? Should it be done in the Controller or in the Model? Should I create a mappable class? what should it look like?

Comment: Can you please show the code where you send the form data?